# Send audio file using with xmpp

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xmppframework

I am using xmpp framework in my application for chat functionality. I have sent the Image but how can i send the Audio file using this. Any idea.

Comment: Can you wrap audio file by Base64 method?

Comment: I have used for image and when i do the same for audio file and send wiht [self.xmppStream sendElement:message]; it cannot send the audio data but image data is send.

Comment: You can convert any `NSData` to Base64 data, it shouldn't depends on content of data.

Comment: I have use Base64 to convert audio file in to data but could not send it to server. i am using xmpp server and gtalk for sending.Do you have any idea how to do it.

Comment: I till not get why you cannot send it to server? You will get plain text. What the problem to send it as usual msg with special prefix to determine audio-file?

Comment: Have a look at XEP-0065: SOCKS5 Bytestreams. XMPPFramework offers this XEP for peer-to-peer bytestreams.

Comment: I think you can send maximum of 64KB in single message. As @chris said you need to use [XEP-65](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html)

Comment: Try to use XEP-0096 http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html

Comment: Can you help me that how we can send image file in Xmpp ?